# LWP::UserAgent и кириллический домен

Tags: perl

Почему то не хочет вытягивать кириллический домен, что бы придумать?
сам скрипт cохранен как UTF-8, запускается кроном

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use utf8;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;

$domain = 'http://кто.рф/';
print Dumper $domain;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120121 Firefox/3.0.5');
$res = $ua->get($domain);
if ($res->is_success) { print $res->content; }
else { print $res->status_line; }
```

ответ приходит на мыло:

```
$VAR1 = "http://\x{43a}\x{442}\x{43e}.\x{440}\x{444}/";
500 Can't connect to кто.рф:80 (Bad hostname 'кто.рф')
```

Answer (score 1):

Punycode использовать надо

Comment: Не надо, LWP прекрасно сам справляется. Просто надо читать маны про UTF8 в Perl.

Comment: @klopp c utf8 в ранних версиях вообще мешанина, а т.к. мы не знаем что за версия перла, пусть будет punycode.. будет работать везде))

Comment: Для корректного преобразования нам всё равно нужно знать, в "каком именно utf" находится строка. Если, конечно, мы говорим о правильных путях типа Net::IDN::Encode, а не о самопальных велосипедах. А раз мы с utf всё равно должны разбираться, то зачем лишние действия?


Но в принципе - да, up-to-date модули и не работать под Windows - залог здоровья :)


P.S. А то бывают и такие велосипеды, встречал, да...

    eval
    {
        $hst = URI->new($url)->ihost();
        $hst = domain_to_unicode($hst) if $hst =~ /^xn\-\-\-/;
        $hst = decode('utf8', $hst);
    };
    if($@ || !$hst) {...}

Comment: разбираюсь с этим...
Centos 6.5 perl.i686 4:5.10.1-136.el6 не могу найти ни одного модуля Punycode что бы ставился с базового репо...

Comment: См. Net::IDN::Encode

Но это костыль для данного случая, если url в "нормальном" utf (с точки зрения перла), то он не нужен.

Comment: костыль тоже не сработал...
ставится версия  perl-Net-LibIDN-0.12-3.el6.i686 а тут нет ::Encode

Comment: Не знаю, что такое "0.12-3", но в CPAN текущая версия [2.100](http://search.cpan.org/~cfaerber/Net-IDN-Encode-2.100/lib/Net/IDN/Encode.pm) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict; # без - убивать на месте
use utf8;
use Encode qw(decode);
# ...
my $domain = 'http://кто.рф/';
# ...
my $res = $ua->get(decode('utf8', $domain));
```

Comment: Cannot decode string with wide characters at /usr/lib/perl5/Encode.pm line 174.

Comment: Значит, что-то не так с кодировкой $domain. Или версиями модулей. Или ещё где-то. У меня, например, исходный пример прекрасно работает и без decode(), оно может быть нужно если данные приходят откуда-то снаружи, например.

Comment: та на локалке у меня и первый код работает. а вот на сервере не хочет. см. разговор с klopp

Answer (score 0):

все дело в том, что официальный Centos 6.5 не поддерживает свежие версии модулей, в связи с этим использование невозможно. Как вариант на свой страх и риск ставить модули из CPAN. но это черевато тем, что могут поломаться зависимые файлы. Будем ждать обновления Centos.

Comment: `sudo cpan -i Net::IDN::Encode`

До сих пор оно корректно разрешало зависимости.